# I have the error MIPS “spim: (parser) syntax error” when I running the code

Tags: arrays, c, mips

I have this C code to find the greater element in the array I want to translate it to MPIS code. I can't figure out what the problem is. can anyone help me and thanks.but I have spim parser syntax error at line "subi $t0,$t0,1"

```
int main(void)
{
   int array[] = {10, 2, 7, 5, 15, 30, 8, 6}; // input array

   int max = array[0];  

   int maxindex=0;

   int arraySize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);


  int i=0;
 
    for(i=0; i < arraySize; i++){
        if(array[i] > max){
             max=array[i]; 
             maxindex=i;
        }
    }

      printf("Max Element is: %d, present at index %d", max,maxindex);


   return 0;
}
```

```
.data

array: .word 10 2 7 5 15

arraysize: .word 5

str1: .asciiz "The maximum number is:"

str2: .asciiz "\n It is at index:"

.text

.globl main

main:


lw $t3, arraysize

la $t0,array

li $t6, -999

li $t7,0

while:

mul $t4,$t3,4

add $t4,$t4,$t0

lw $t4,($t4)

ble $t4,$t6, maxi

move $t6,$t4

move $t7,$t3

maxi:

subi $t3,$t3,1

bgtz $t8, while

li $v0,4

la $a0, str1

syscall

li $v0,1

move $a0,$t6

syscall

li $v0,4

la $a0, str2

syscall

li $v0,1

move $a0,$t7

syscall
```

Comment: _"I have spim parser syntax error at line "subi $t0,$t0,1""_. There's no such line if the code you've shown us. Anyway, `subi` is not an actual MIPS instruction. It might be a pseudo-instruction supported by some MIPS assemblers. So check the documentation for your simulator to see if it supports `subi`. Or just use `addi` with a negative number instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the C compiler. The problem is that your program is very trivial and compiler will figure out the result of it, only leaving the call to `printf`.

```
size_t findMax(const int *array, const size_t size)
{
   int max = array[0];  
   size_t maxindex = 0;

    if(size >= 2)
    {
        for(size_t i = 1; i < size; i++){
            if(array[i] > max){
                    max=array[i]; 
                    maxindex=i;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxindex;
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = {10, 2, 7, 5, 15, 30, 8, 6}; // input array

    size_t arraySize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    size_t maxindex = findMax(array, arraySize);

    printf("Max Element is: %d, present at index %zu", array[maxindex], maxindex);


    return 0;
}
```

and the code priced by the C compiler:

```
findMax:
        sltu    $3,$5,2
        bne     $3,$0,$L8
        move    $2,$0

        lw      $6,0($4)
        li      $3,1                        # 0x1
        addiu   $4,$4,4
$L4:
        lw      $7,0($4)
        nop
        slt     $8,$6,$7
        beq     $8,$0,$L3
        nop

        move    $2,$3
        move    $6,$7
$L3:
        addiu   $3,$3,1
        bne     $5,$3,$L4
        addiu   $4,$4,4

$L8:
        j       $31
        nop

$LC1:
        .ascii  "Max Element is: %d, present at index %zu\000"
$LC0:
        .word   10
        .word   2
        .word   7
        .word   5
        .word   15
        .word   30
        .word   8
        .word   6
main:
        addiu   $sp,$sp,-64
        lui     $5,%hi($LC0)
        li      $6,32                 # 0x20
        addiu   $4,$sp,24
        sw      $31,60($sp)
        jal     memcpy
        addiu   $5,$5,%lo($LC0)

        addiu   $4,$sp,24
        jal     findMax
        li      $5,8                        # 0x8

        sll     $3,$2,2
        addiu   $4,$sp,24
        addu    $3,$4,$3
        lw      $5,0($3)
        lui     $4,%hi($LC1)
        move    $6,$2
        jal     printf
        addiu   $4,$4,%lo($LC1)

        lw      $31,60($sp)
        move    $2,$0
        j       $31
        addiu   $sp,$sp,64
```